# How do I write to an array that's already been created using malloc in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to write to an array that was created on the heap using malloc in ARM assembly. I cannot seem to figure out how. When I try printing the array in my .cpp file just prints a value of 0.

Currently I have this.

```
    .text
    .global wr

     wr:
     push {lr}
     mov r0, #12
     mov r1, #5
     mov r2, #6
     mov r3, #7
     mov r7, #0

     bl malloc

     pop {lr}
     mov pc, lr
     str r1, [r0, r7, lsl #2]
     add r7, r7, #1
     str r2, [r0, r7, lsl #2]
     add r7, r7, #1
     str r3, [r0, r7, lsl #2]

     mov pc, lr
```

I'll probably put it into a loop in the future but I just want to write to the array at this moment.

edit: I changed the name from "write" to "wr."

Comment: You do realize your writing code is never reached because you return from your function using `mov pc, lr`? Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: `write` is a bad choice of function name.  There's already a POSIX standard function called that: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

Comment: No. I didn't realize that Jester. Can you recommend a debugger? I'm just doing this in Linux terminal using the g++-arm-linux compiler. I can't seem to figure out how to get gdb to run step by step in order to test the code.

Comment: `stepi` or `si` is the step instruction in gdb.

Comment: Thank you Jester.